# Post request works fine in postman but I can't make it work with Swift 4 and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am developing a **Swift 4** application, which talks to a **JAVA DAO** that communicates with a **DB2** database using **JDBC**.  I am using **JAX-RS** to provide the Web services capability. I am also using the **Alamofire 4** library as part of the application.

When I make the call to the DAO using a POST request, which passes a series of parameters with a content-type of x-www-URLEncoded in Postman the call, completes successfully and a result is passed back with a 200 msg, but when I tried it in Swift 4 using an Alamofire request the JAVA DAO throws an error at the resultset of the DAO.

Error

> [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [app.log] [tid: _ThreadID=31
>   _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1517241179331] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Exception :
>   java.lang.NullPointerExceptioncom.sun.gjc.spi.base.ResultSetWrapper.next(ResultSetWrapper.java:103)

```
Java code

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)


public int insertUserProfile(
      @FormParam("password") String password,         
      @FormParam("fName") String fName,
      @FormParam("city") String city,
      @FormParam("stateProv") String stateProv,
      @FormParam("zip") String zip,
      @FormParam("emailId") String emailId,
      @FormParam("age") short age,
      @FormParam("sex") String sex,
      @FormParam("uType") String uType,
      @FormParam("salary") BigDecimal salary,
      @FormParam("occupation") String occupation,
      @FormParam("secQuestion") String secQuestion,
      @FormParam("secAnswer") String secAnswer
         ) throws Exception{


 try {

   String proc = "CALL USERINFO(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   int whichquery = 1;
   int cols = 1;


   CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(proc);

   stmt.setInt(1,whichquery);
   stmt.setInt(2,0);
   stmt.setString(3,password);
   stmt.setString(4,fName);
   stmt.setString(5,city);
   stmt.setString(6,stateProv);
   stmt.setString(7,zip);
   stmt.setString(8,emailId);
   stmt.setInt(9,age);
   stmt.setString(10,sex);
   stmt.setString(11,uType);
   stmt.setBigDecimal(12,salary);
   stmt.setString(13,occupation);
   stmt.setString(14,secQuestion);
   stmt.setString(15,secAnswer);
   stmt.registerOutParameter(16,Types.VARCHAR, sqlState);
   stmt.registerOutParameter(17,Types.INTEGER, sqlCode);
   stmt.registerOutParameter(18,Types.VARCHAR, sqlMsg);
  if (debug_sw) { System.out.println("***** setString *****"); }




   rs = stmt.executeQuery();

   if (debug_sw) { System.out.println("***** executeQuery *****"); }

   if (debug_sw) { System.out.println("***** Initialized list *****"); }

   if (sqlCode == 0 && rs.next() )
   {
     total_rows = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
   }



  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();

  if (debug_sw) { System.out.println("***** Closed rs, stmt, & conn *****"); }

  if (debug_sw) { System.out.println("***** Returning JSONArray *****"); }

  return total_rows;
```

Swift 4 / Alamofire code

```
  let parameters: Parameters = [
                        "password":passW,
                        "fName":fname,
                        "city":cityname,
                        "stateProv":statename,
                        "zip": zipname,
                        "emailId": emailname,
                        "age": agename,
                        "sex": sexname,
                        "uType":userTypeName,
                        "salary":salaryAmount,
                        "occupation": occupationname,
                        "secQuestion": secretQuestion,
                        "secAnswer": secretAnswer
                        ]
                      Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, 
                      parameters:parameter, encoding:URLEncoding.default)
                      .reponse{response in
                       print("The output is: ",response, request!.description)
                       }
```

PostMan code

```
      POST /dao/webapi/myprofile HTTP/1.1
      Host: localhost:8080
      Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      Cache-Control: no-cache
      Postman-Token: 7681b040-1a3bo-1k0k-21b8-c7993b32ab28

        password=dusty962!&fName=george&city=glassfish&
        stateProv=NJ&zip=09023&emailId=douglas%40test.com&
        age=1960&sex=male&uType=U&salary=6&occupation=programmer
        &secQuestion=married&secAnswer=twice
```

Comment: Thanks Don, It was a typo in my post on stackoverflow.  I enter it as parameters in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameter instead of parameters to the request method. Is this just a typo in your question submission or do you have a parameter variable? I assume Xcode would let you know if you didn't.

Comment: The parameters entry is correct in my code, but it still doesn't work.